# Task runtime is too long, but the call stack is amost empty

Tags: javascript, performance, task

I am trying to perf the web page with the Performance Tools in Google, and I find that, this task took a long time to finish, but the call stack within this task is nearly empty.

Abnormal task runtime:
[image: abnormal task runtime]

Task comparation:
[image: task comparation]

Comment: What kind of an answer are you expecting to get?

Comment: I'm not sure whether  the webworker or something else cause this problem

Comment: There's no way for us to tell you what's wrong, if we can't see your code. Note, that you just should not dump your code to the post, nor just link to your site. See how to create a [mre].

Comment: What's the question here? you expose well the facts, but no problem or question is shared...